# Omipay PayPal - Credit Card on Landing Page

Tags: credit-card, omnipay, paypal

I have a Laravel application using Omnipay/PayPal (PayPal Express) and I can't get it to redirect to the Credit Card landing page.

Is this possible?

I have *solutionType* set to *Sole* and *landingPage* set to *Billing*, but I always get PayPal's sign in form.

I have read a lot, and these two parameters shoud do it.

Even if I follow [Omnipay's example](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#example-application), the same happens: can't get to the Credit Card landing page.

I'm using a Sandbox test account, and *testMode* is set to *true*.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can do what you are trying to do -- have a customer sent to the PayPal credit card capture page for non-PayPal members, without allowing the customer to sign in to their PayPal account first.

I would suggest you have a read on PayPal Experience profiles.  I don't know if or how this works with the express gateway but it does work with the REST gateway.  In any case I advise people to switch to the REST gateway because it is more up to date and better documented.